# Adding custom protocol to UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have some forms for the authentications and signup views and I want that all UITextField inside those forms have a UIButton as an accessory view, just above the keyboard. I want to have the possibility to set the title and the action for this button

Because I want all those text field have one and each will have a title and an action, and to avoid redundancy, I thought about a protocol.
I want something like extending a custom protocol, for example UITextFieldAccessoryViewDelegate and to be conform to some functions like :
-buttonAccessoryView title ... -> String
-didClickOnAccessoryViewButton.. -> ()

My mind is closed. Someone can give me some ideas to do what I want ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you right, you want a protocol for UITextField to have a UIButton?

Comment: A button in the accessory text field view yes, and the possibility to set the button title and target action, for each UITextField

Comment: so you just need a category with a UIButton, since the UIButton methods let you add title and action.

Comment: I'm using swift and I can't add stored property using extension

Answer (score 0):

You could use [associated objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/index.html) to solve this problem. This lets you add a property and its synthesized getter/setters.

```
@interface UITextField(AccessoryButton)

@property(readwrite, strong, nonatomic) UIButton *accessoryButton;

@end

#import<objc/runtime.h>
@implementation UITextField(AccessoryButton)

-(UIButton*) accessoryButton
{
    objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(accessoryButton));
}

-(void) setAccessoryButton:(UIButton *)accessoryButton
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(accessoryButton), accessoryButton, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}
```

Include this category into your forms that need the UIButton for the text fields. Then assign action and title to a UIButton like how you normally do.

Answer (score 0):

Considering everything you want to do I think you are better off using a subclass of UITextField rather than an extension.

Extensions can't add instance variables to the objects they extend, but subclasses can. As lead_the_zeppelin points out in his answer, you can use associated objects to simulate adding instance variables with an extension but it seems like you're making it needlessly complicated when a subclass gives you everything you want.